# how to create new user in Raspberry PI who has equal privileges as default user: pi?

Tags: raspbian, user

I am new to Raspberry PI. I need to create new user in Raspberry PI in Raspbian distro, but I would like to have different username but with equal or same level of privileges?
How could I do it?

Comment: Why do you want to do this, Is this login for someone else to use? if you are duplicating the permissions and you are the one using the account  I don't see the benefit. This thread https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=91&t=37324  and particularly the answer from @joan (another user here) will get you started.

Comment: I have another Raspberry PI which also I need to ssh. Having same name in ssh is not helping me. But, I want to have same level of privileges for new user.

Comment: The problem would appear to be with your SSH toolchain and prompt, so why not address it with a custom prompt and better SSH tools, instead of creating a bigger attack surface for hackers. What are you using to SSH? What type of computer are you SSHing from? What command are you using that is confusing you? are you SSHing using a hostname or IP address?

Comment: Hi Steve. My two PIs are connected to local network. I would like to ssh to them using terminal in my pc. So, while I ssh to both of them at once what I get is pi@raspberrypi in both terminals. So, I would like to have different users but with same or equal level of privileges of default user pi. Thanks.

Comment: wouldn't changing host names be a whole lot easier/safer? so you could SSH to applepie and blueberrypie with ssh pi@applepie or ssh pi@blueberrypie?

Comment: @SteveRobillard: For consistency, I'd recommend one spelling of 'pi/pie' though ;)

Comment: @Jacobm001 fixed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you run `adduser` with the same group as `pi` this should work (I haven't tried this).

As per the comments above this is the hard way to solve your problem. Just give each Pi an unique `hostname` and they should be easy to distinguish.

It is preferable to have the same username on each machine if you want to move files around.

Answer (score 21):

Assuming a new name of *username*:

To create a new user account: `sudo addduser username` Follow the prompts, being sure to set a good password when prompted.

You also want to add the new user to the same groups that the pi user belongs to. You can view the groups the pi users belongs to with `groups pi`.

> groups pi pi : pi adm dialout cdrom sudo audio video plugdev games
>   users netdev input spi i2c gpio

Note that your new user will automatically have a group created matching their username. You do not need to add your new user to the `pi` group.

You can add your new user to each group individually using `sudo adduser username groupname`. For example:

`sudo adduser username sudo
sudo adduser username audio`

If you want your new user to have the exact same rights as the pi user, add the new username to all of the groups except the `pi` group that the pi user belongs to. You can save some typing by doing this in one pass:

`for GROUP in adm dialout cdrom sudo audio video plugdev games users netdev input spi i2c gpio; do sudo adduser username $GROUP; done`

Be sure to add your new user to the `sudo` group since that is what allows the use of the `sudo` command by the new user. `netdev` can be important for configuring network devices.

As others have noted, you're probably better off simply changing your hostname (can be done with `sudo raspi-config` under `Advanced->Hostname`) to accomplish what you're after. Also, don't forget the old pi account still exists, and possibly with a default password, so be sure to at least change the password for the pi user for security reasons.

Comment: Better (to avoid typing groups) `for GROUP in $(groups pi | sed 's/.*:\spi//'); do sudo adduser username $GROUP; done`

Comment: Better so long as figuring out the correct regexp doesn't take longer! Are you guaranteed "pi" will always be the 1st group listed after the username? I don't see anything in the `groups` manpage. I throw my new user in other groups (e.g. `sshusers`) as well upon creation.

Comment: I don't have any problem with RE, at least simple ones like this. If `pi` isn't 1st  it will fail to delete it.

Comment: Was thinking more of a new user such as the OP!